# Django: Multiple database for read and write independent of app

Tags: django, django-orm, multiple-databases, django-database

How can we work with multiple databases on Django, under some specific conditions such as,
1. One DB for write purpose only ( `db_for_write.sqlite3`)
2. Two other DB for reading purposes (`read_replica_1.sqlite3` ,`read_replica_2.sqlite3`)
3. All these 3 DB should be synchronized all the time (3 DB should contain same data all the time)
4. All the actions such as `CRUD` , `migration` etc are independent of `app` or `model`
this is my **Db_Router.py**

```
import random


class ExampleDatabaseRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        db_list = ('db_for_read_1', 'db_for_read_2')
        return random.choice(db_list)

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'db_for_write_only'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        # I couldn't understand what would do this method
        return

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        # sync all DB
        return
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the purpose of `allow_relation()` method. I hope someone could help me.

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers),

> **allow_relation(obj1, obj2, **hints)¶**
>
> Return **True** if a relation between obj1 and obj2 should be allowed, False if the relation should be prevented, or None if the router has no opinion. **This is purely a validation operation, used by foreign key and many to many operations to determine if a relation should be allowed between two objects.**

As in the documentation, this method only determines if the objects passed into it are eligible to create a relation between them. When using multiple databases, there may arise a situation where tables from separate databases require a relationship between them, but Django currently doesn't support these kind of relationships, which are often referred as `cross-database relationships`. This is because of referential integrity. In order to maintain a relationship between two objects, Django needs to know that the primary key of the related object is valid. If the primary key is stored on a separate database, it’s not possible to easily evaluate the validity of a primary key.

If you need to look more into cross-database relationships, then django documentation provides a much better [explanation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#no-cross-database-relations).

Actually, Django documentation covers pretty much everything about routers. A pretty basic example have also included [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example).

Comment: as far I understood from your explanation, in my case, there is no chance for a **cross-database relationships**. Am I right ? .Then How can I sync my three DB all the time ? Can you hep me